# aurelia.use.globalResources(..) looks for html file instead of module

Tags: webpack, aurelia

I am using the Aurelia Webpack skeleton and trying to setup a global resource. I register the resource like this in my `main.ts` file:

```
aurelia.use
.standardConfiguration()
.developmentLogging()
.globalResources(['service/globalResource']);
```

And here is my folder structure:

[image: Folder Structure]

But I get this error in the console:

[image: Error]

For some reason it's looking for an `html` file instead of resolving the module. I know that the `globalResource.ts` file is registered in webpack. Here's the `webpack module registration map` showing that:

[image: Map]

Why is Aurelia trying to resolve `./service/globalResource.html` instead of resolving the `./service/globalResource` module that's registered with Webpack?

Comment: Looking at your structure I am assuming service/globalResource is not really something related to the view i.e. it is not a converter, custom attribute or custom element, is that correct?

Comment: No it's a @singleton()

Comment: Is there something specific you are trying to achieve by making a service global? Did you intend to use the service in your view directly?

Comment: I'd like to use it without having to import it anywhere.

Comment: Can you use `./` instead of `/` to lead the path?

Comment: @PWKad I tried both with no luck

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I cannot comment. I think you are not exporting a function with the name `configure`in your `globalResources.ts`, thus `aurelia` treats it as a custom element, which lead to that error. I could be wrong, but if possible, maybe a simplified down version of your `globalResources.ts` could give more clue.

Answer (score 0):

use @noView over your class.

suppose   MyGlobalResource (my-globalresource.ts) is component which I want to make global without using html template then in my-globalresource.ts file I will put @noView like this.

```
import {noView} from 'aurelia-framework';
   @noView
   export class MyGlobalResource{
     messageByComponent : string = "This is message from My Component";
   }
```